# Craft 3 Redis configuration error

Tags: cache, php, redis

when following the information for [enabling Redis in Craft 3](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/configuration.html#redis), my site just refreshes to a blank screen with a "Internal server error" generic message. Reviewing the server logs reveals:

```
ReflectionException: Class yii\redis\Cache does not exist in /storage/path/www/staging_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:428
```

Talking with my hosting provider (Arcustech), informs me that Redis is indeed running and php-redis is installed. The details I entered into `config\app.php` were

```
return [
'components' => [
    'cache' => [
        'class' => yii\redis\Cache::class,
        'defaultDuration' => 86400,
        'redis' => [
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

Any light that could be shone onto my predicament would be amazing.
thanks!

Comment: Did you install the Yii2 library as well? Because it doesn't seem so

Comment: OK beginner comment, so forgive me, but where do I install the Yii2 library, in the main Craft directory?

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-redis/blob/master/README.md. You require "yiisoft/yii2-redis": "~2.0.0". You should not have a main Craft directory in the best case

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a beginners mistake, thank you to Robin in the comments above for setting me on the right track. All that was required to install was the Yii2 library, once this was done all worked as expected.